# Django FormWizard Keep Values Between Steps

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I'm new in Django and I.m trying to do a FormWizard. The example work but the when I move between steps(not submit) the form does not keep or retain the data already typed.
How could I keep the data moving back and forward?

```
# forms.py
class ContactForm1(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

class ContactForm2(forms.Form):
    sender = forms.CharField(required=False)

class ContactForm3(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=False)

# views.py
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "contact_form.html"

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
        return render_to_response('done.html', {'form_data': form_data})
```

Comment: Did you setup your sessions correctly?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I did it as the docs explain. I dont know if I need to do something else. I though that functionality should be by default.